# Use of UNITY_MATRIX_MV is detected

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I took a billboard shader from the internet but I have this warning message that says "Shader warning in 'Custom/Billboard': Use of UNITY_MATRIX_MV is detected. To transform a vertex into view space, consider using UnityObjectToViewPos for better performance."

I'm not sure how to correct the code with the new function. Here is the shader:

```
Shader "Custom/Billboard"
{
    Properties{
       _MainTex("Texture Image", 2D) = "white" {}
       _ScaleX("Scale X", Float) = 1.0
       _ScaleY("Scale Y", Float) = 1.0
    }
        SubShader{
           Tags{"Queue" = "Transparent" "RenderType" = "Transparent" }
           Pass{
           CGPROGRAM
           #include "UnityCG.cginc"
           #pragma vertex vert  
           #pragma fragment frag

           uniform sampler2D _MainTex;
           uniform float _ScaleX;
           uniform float _ScaleY;

           struct vertexInput {
              float4 vertex : POSITION;
              float4 tex : TEXCOORD0;
           };

           struct vertexOutput {
              float4 pos : POSITION;
              float4 tex : TEXCOORD0;
           };

           vertexOutput vert(vertexInput input)
           {
              vertexOutput output;

              output.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_P,
                 mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MV, float4(0,0,0,1))
                 + float4(input.vertex.xyz, 0));

              output.tex = input.tex;

              return output;
           }

           float4 frag(vertexOutput input) : COLOR
           {
              return tex2D(_MainTex, float2(input.tex.xy));
           }

           ENDCG
        }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to do anything. If you do want to change it though, if nothing else just to make the warning go away, you can replace this:

```
mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MV, float4(0,0,0,1))
```

With this:

```
UnityObjectToViewPos((float3)0)
```